# Rest-assured. Is it possible to extract JSONObject/JSONArray from response json?

Tags: java, rest-api, json, rest-assured, jsonpath

I'm Using RestAssured,
and i'm getting the response like this-

```
 {
        "Data": {
            "Sub": {
                "SubDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrgId": 5,
                        "SubId": 1,
                        "SubName": "Mathematics"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "RawData": {
            "Url": "http://localhost:11111/cases/case-15",
            "Type": "Rest",
            "Request": {
                "Details": {
                    "OrganizationId": 5,
                    "Student": {
                        "Age": 30,
                        "Religion": "Hindu",
                        "StudentId": 10
                    }
                }
            },
            "Response": {
                "SmartReturnObject": {
                    "Subject": [
                        {
                            "SubjectId": 1,
                            "SubjectName": "Mathematics"
                        }
                    ],
                    "OrganizationId": 5
                }
            },
            "IsApiError": false
        },
        "SessionId": "5q0",
        "RequestUniqueId": "4543534",
        "StatusCode": "4540000",
        "StatusMessage": "Success",
        "DataSource": "DD"
    }
```

Now i need to extract the **Data** object separate and **RawData** separate but I failed.
I tried with JSONPath also but not getting it in JSON format.
**I tried**

```
      JsonPath body= response.jsonPath();
      Object value=body.get("Data");
      System.out.println("Value is-"+value);
```

and getting it like this - `{Sub={SubDetails=[{OrgId=5, SubId=1, SubName=Mathematics}]}}`
I want the response as **instanceof JSONObject** or **JSONArray** type.Response can be dynamic like `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` can be at any place.

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I want to get ``Data`` object and ``RawData`` object separately from response, in instanceof ``JSONObject``or ``JSONArray`` type (in whatever format response is)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? if you want to send that response using the next request then you can just reuse the string.

Comment: Actually, I need to dynamically traverse the complete JSON and then i have to match it with other Expected JSON, so that i can identify that at which placea any Key Value pair or any structure is different from expected one.

Answer (score 1):

Why is this not an option?

```
JsonPath resJson= new JsonPath(response);
JsonPath referrenceJson= new JsonPath(jsonTOCompare);
Assert.assertEquals(resJson.get("fields"), referrenceJson.get("fields"));
```

Comment: Because i want to compare each property, and if any mismatch happen then i need to know that whether key not matched or any value not matched. Also some time i got the scenario like i need to ignore the some property during compare.

Comment: Could you provide a real example of what you tried to achieve but failed? Something that you think it will not work with the suggested solution?

Comment: you can edit the question add something like i wanted to compare {a:1} with [{a:2}] . Tried suggested answer but got this error

Comment: I need to compare the response json to json coming from .json file, by using your way i can't do that until i will not get the response in instance of JSONObject or JSONArray.